# Java variable issue with Tesseract OCR

Tags: java, spring-boot, variables, ocr, tesseract

I used this code in Spring Boot Java to create an OCR application.

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "upload";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public RedirectView singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                   RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model) throws IOException, TesseractException {

        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/ashwi/Downloads/javaocr9/src/main/resources/static" + file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);

        File convFile = convert(file);
        Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
        tesseract.setDatapath("C:/Users/ashwi/Downloads/ocr-tess4j-example-master/ocr-tess4j-example-master/tessdata");
        String text = tesseract.doOCR(file2);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("file", file);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("text", text);
        return new RedirectView("result");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/result")
    public String result() {
        return "result";
    }

    public static File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        convFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
    }
}
```

However, there appears to be an error at:

```
 String text = tesseract.doOCR(file2);
```

In visual studio code, I got an error saying: "file2 cannot be resolved to a variable".

Any ideas? I am new to Java and am having trouble fixing it.

I got this version of code from: https://stackabuse.com/tesseract-simple-java-optical-character-recognition/

Comment: file2 is a variable that is not initialized. You must give something like File file2 = new File("C:/");

Comment: Can you please be more specific with a solution? I am new to Java, sorry.